# Hyper-V frambuffer driver not working correctly

Tags: drivers, kernel, framebuffer, hyper-v

Running the up to date Alpha of Xubuntu 13.10 on Hyper-V (WIndows 8 Pro) I noticed the included Hyper-V frambuffer driver does not work as expected. According to the commit message (http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=68a2d20b79b105f02dcbc52c211d7e62f98996b7) the version included in Kernel 3.10 should allow full HD resolution and fix the double mouse curser issue. Unfortunally neither of that work here.

Kernel version is 3.10.0-6. `lsmod` confirms the hyperv_fb module is loaded. Anybody has a clue how to make the framebuffer work as expectd?

EDIT: I filed a bug about this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1218995

Comment: Did you have any luck in the past weeks? does it work for you now?

Comment: No, I updated to the latest development kernel (based on 3.11 in the mean time) and the problem still exists. It seems something in the video stack prevents it from taking advantage of the new kernel module.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1199345
Please see fix bug in Linux Kernel 3.13 and install 14.04 Trusty.

Comment: Thanks, saw the patch in 3.13 already. I have a trusty VM, in fact I am just waiting for 3.13 rc to come out to test.